# Creating one TIN for each iterated point and line dataset from gdb using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder

I need to create a TIN for every line/point dataset out of two geodatabeses. The point and line datasets have the same ending name.

This is my approach how to build up the model:

[image]

Am I missing something in the process of creating a TIN for each iterated feature?

Comment: Yes, the model creates one TIN. But I need a TIN of each iterated line/point feature class.

Comment: You're referencing 'Value' in your Create TIN tool, but there is not 'Value' variable in your model.  You need to use %Name%?